# Composition of smooth maps on smooth manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

My questions concerns the proof of the fact that the composition of smooth maps on smooth
manifolds is again a smooth map. In most literature the proof is written to be a trivial
implication of the fact that this property holds at the level of charts.
However, Im trying to write this down rigorously with the correctly defined charts.

**Proposition:** Let $\mathcal{M}$,$\mathcal{N}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ be smooth manifolds. Let $F\colon \mathcal{M}\to \mathcal{N}$
and $G\colon \mathcal{N} \to \mathcal{B}$ be smooth maps. Then the composition
$G\circ F\colon \mathcal{M} \to \mathcal{B}$ is smooth as well.

*Proof*:
Let $p \in \mathcal{M}$. Since $F$ is smooth, we know that there exist charts
$(U,\varphi)$ with $p\in U$ and $(V,\psi)$ with $F(p) \in V$ such that
$F(U)\subseteq V$ and $\psi \circ F \circ \varphi^{-1}\colon \varphi(U)\to \psi(V)$ is smooth.
Since $G$ is smooth there further exist charts $(\tilde{V},\tilde{\psi})$
with $F(p)\in \tilde{V}$ and $(W,\rho)$ with $G(F(p))\in W$ such that
$G(\tilde{V})\subseteq W$ and $\rho \circ G \circ \tilde{\psi}^{-1}\colon \tilde{\psi}(\tilde{V})\to \rho(W)$ is smooth.
Now consider the intersection $V\cap \tilde{V}$. Certainly $V\cap \tilde{V}$
is open as intersection of open sets. Further, the restriction of a
homeomorphism is again a homeomorphism, hence
$(V\cap \tilde{V},\psi\vert_{V\cap \tilde{V}})$ is a chart on $\mathcal{N}$
containing $F(p)$.
$F$ is smooth and thus in particular continuous, therefore
$\text{preim}_{F}(V\cap \tilde{V})$ is open and we can intersect it with $U$
to obtain the chart $(U\cap \text{preim}_{F}(V\cap \tilde{V}), \varphi\vert_{
 U\cap \text{preim}_{F}(V\cap \tilde{V})})$ on $\mathcal{M}$ containing $p$.

Now
\begin{equation*}
\rho \circ G \circ F \circ \varphi\vert_{U\cap \text{preim}_{F}(
V\cap \tilde{V})}^{-1} = \rho \circ G \circ \psi\vert_{V\cap \tilde{V}}^{-1} \circ \psi\vert_{V\cap \tilde{V}}\circ F \circ \varphi\vert_{U\cap \text{preim}_{F}(V\cap \tilde{V})}^{-1}
\end{equation*}
is smooth from $\varphi\vert_{U\cap \text{preim}_{F}(V\cap \tilde{V})}(U\cap \text{preim}_{F}(V\cap \tilde{V}))$ to $\rho(W)$ as composition of smooth maps.
Hence $G\circ F$ is smooth.
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Is this proof correct and also complete?

Comment: With the way you defined them, $\psi$ and $\tilde \psi$ need not coincide. However you may take $\tilde\psi =\psi$ (or any other smooth chart for that matter).

Comment: In my opinion you're making this too difficult. You can start with what you wrote on the last line, and then simply introduce the identity $\psi^{-1}\circ \psi$ in between $G$ and $F$. Then you just have to keep track of what set's you're mapping to.

Comment: I see now, since the smoothness condition is chart independent I have the freedom to choose $(\tilde{V},\tilde{\psi}) = (V,\psi)$, i.e., the same chart on $\mathcal{N}$ which makes things much easier and clearer. Thank you.